# How else can I improve this question about PC-tailored homebrew?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, homebrew

The question: [Does PC-tailored homebrew require special considerations?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162516)

My first draft was written poorly and I fully understand why it was closed so fast. Now I believe I addressed all the issues raised in the comments. Is there a way to salvage the question?

I'm still adamant on it being a general [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) question; a [homebrew-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-review)-style version of the question would receive too specific answers for my liking.

Answer (score 1):

### Your questions could do with more focus

It's a hard question to answer. Generally homebrew is most balanced when it is most similar to existing content. There are certainly a lot of situational and niche content which is balanced. With regards to complexity, there are some complex class features, most tend to be 1 or 2 sentences but there are some with as many as 5 sentences. Homebrew already adds complexity since it is new too.

Your title and 3 questions asked within are all difficult and broad:

- **Does PC-tailored homebrew require special considerations?** This is a hard question to answer objectively.
- **Is making a functionality (replacement class feature, new feat, a spell) with complex requirements a bad design?** Bad in what way? You probably shouldn't make something more complex than the most complex feature, but why not, there's nothing wrong with it.
- **What about feature synergising with other optional ones?** What are you asking? General thoughts?
- **How to ensure an option filling very specific gap is balanced across different play-styles?** Which play styles are you talking about? There are play styles where balance doesn't even exist, let alone adherence to rules.

This question is very broad, and I'm not sure how you will measure a good answer. For example if you ask "are complex requirements bad design?" how can I answer? What does "bad" mean? How complex are we talking? Even if you answer those, how can we discern a good answer from a bad answer?

I understand that you are asking about balance, and making niche features still useful for different playstyles. Beyond that, there are a lot of very broad and vague questions that are so hard to answer!

I think you should consider your goal and ask a more direct question, I think your goal is something like: "I want to make content that is niche, but still useful and balanced." As for the question, I'm not sure exactly, it seems to be "how do I do that?"

Comment: I agree that 4th point is too broad, but let me explain what I expect from others.

Comment: > Does PC-tailored homebrew require special considerations?

"No, even general homebrew needs to take into account edge cases and table dynamics to ensure that it doesn't outshine other players." (I'm makint it up as I go)

> Is making a functionality (replacement class feature, new feat, a spell) with complex requirements a bad design?

You actually gave an answer IMO.

> What about feature synergising with other optional ones?

"Yes, this is very uncommon for invocations to work very well with specific feat. The closest that comes to my mind is Champion Fighter with Sentinel feat"

Comment: Do you think these questions could be separated into three different ones?

Comment: @KrzysztofSkibiński Ok, can you tell me how you will judge a good or bad answer? That is a key part of what makes this question hard to answer. It may be better to split it into several questions too. EDIT: yes, I think it would be a good idea :)

Comment: The best answer would show how complex / situational / specific published material can be to point the limit of how innovative homebrew can be without being convoluted. Maybe even with a side note about if and why community considers these "bad".

Comment: @KrzysztofSkibiński Perhaps the question should be something like "what are the most complex class features?" that question can definitely be answered, and will give you something to compare to. Maybe a question like "what are the downsides of having complex features?"

Comment: @KrzysztofSkibiński "What is most complex" is still a fairly subjective answer.  One person might elect a skill that has a configurable geometric shape as most complex (like 5E's Tidal Wave), while another person might think something that is deals with a statistical optimization (like 5E's Savage Attacker) more complicated because there should be statistical analysis for when it is best to reroll the damage.  There is no "this is the most complex skill" answer, which means it lends itself to discussion, which isn't the purpose of SE.